# SwiftUI arrow shortcut does not work on iPad

Tags: swift, swiftui, ipados

In SwiftUI, the arrow shortcuts (without modifier keys) does not seem to work on iPad running iPadOS 14.

```
  Button { ... }.keyboardShortcut(.rightArrow, modifiers: [])
```

However, this seem to work fine on M1 Mac.

Is this a bug? And is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you ever found a workaround for this? It's still the same in iPadOS 16.2 and seems like a bug.